# How do I formulate constraints that check if a parameter is between certain values, using binary variables?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint, constraint-programming, quadratic-programming

I have $3$ parameters $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and a variable $d$ and $3$ binary variables $b_1,b_2,b_3$ and a "result" variable $s$. How do I model constraints so that:

- If $d$ is between $0$ and $a_1$, then $s=1$
- If $d$ is between $a_1$ and $a_2$, then $s =$ ... complex calculation ...
- If $d$ is between $a_2$ and $a_3$, then $s = 0$

I have found a formulation that is as follows:
\begin{align}
a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 - d \le 0 \\
-a_1b_1 - a_2b_2 - a_3b_3 + d \le 0 \\
b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 1
\end{align}

But if use this formulation in my model, the b-variables get calculated incorrectly. Does anyone see the reason why and/or has a better idea?

Comment: If $d$ and $a_i$ are parameters, then you have no modeling to do, the values are known a priori so you can deduce $s$ while pre processing.

Comment: d is a variable. I made a mistake in the Post. I will edit it sorry.

Comment: Does the "complex calculation" for $s$ involve other decision variables, or is it constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your first constraint should instead be
$$0b_1 + a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_3 - d \le 0$$
With this change, the logical implications are
\begin{align}
b_1 = 1 &\implies   0 \le d \le a_1 \\
b_2 = 1 &\implies a_1 \le d \le a_2 \\
b_3 = 1 &\implies a_2 \le d \le a_3
\end{align}

To avoid ambiguous borders, introduce a small tolerance $\epsilon>0$ and impose instead
$$0 b_1 + (a_1+\epsilon) b_2 + (a_2+\epsilon) b_3 - d \le 0$$

Comment: I tried hat and it still didn't calculate the b values correctly. Just for clarification do you mean my constraint should be:

0b1+a1b2+a2b3 - d <= 0

or

0b1+a1b2+a2b3 <= 0?

And also the interval borders would be problematic. I would need:

b1 -> 0 <= d <= a1;

b2 -> a1 < d <= a2;

b3 -> a2 < d <= a3;

Comment: I updated my answer.  You cannot avoid the ambiguous borders without introducing a small tolerance $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Ok I tried changing the first constraint again and now GUROBI concluded that my program is infeasible

Comment: Ok, how would the constraints change if I wanted to simplify my situation:

Let's say I want s = ... if d <= a_1 and s=0 if d > a1

I'm sorry if my questions are dumb but I am really new to this topic

Comment: I suspect that the infeasibility arises from your constraints that link $s$ to $b$.  Try solving without those first to see if the problem is then feasible.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I finally gave up and simplified the problem and my new constraints work

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.